# Cassandra 4.0 - dropping message of type READ_REQ

Tags: cassandra

I have updated my cassandra cluster from 3.11.6 to version 4.0.6. The cluster consists of 3 nodes. I am running the cassandra Nodes as Docker containers on a Debian System.

In general the update works and all seems to be fine. But observing the log files on my nodes I see on all nodes from time to time (once in 3 minutes) the following message:

**dropping message of type READ_REQ whose timeout expired before reaching the network**

```
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-5] 2022-11-06 17:21:04,582 NoSpamLogger.java:92 - /aa.bb.cc.dd:7000->/aa.bb.cc.dd:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-[no-channel] failed to connect
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /aa.bb.cc.dd:7000
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$2.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:576)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
WARN  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-5] 2022-11-06 17:21:07,675 NoSpamLogger.java:95 - /aa.bb.cc.dd:7000->/aa.bb.cc.dd:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-[no-channel] dropping message of type READ_REQ whose timeout expired before reaching the network
```

I am unable to figure out what this message means. Can some one explain what the reason for such messages can be?
I am also running a UFW firewall on each node, if this may be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you described suggest to me that the firewall is too aggressive when marking connections between nodes as idle.

You can either (a) throttle back the firewall rules/configuration, or (b) increase the frequency of the TCP keepalive on the nodes. For example:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w \
  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60 \
  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3 \
  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=10
```

The subject of dropped connections comes up a fair bit so I've decided to post the details in [Why are connections to Cassandra nodes timing-out during low traffic periods?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319984/). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So these look like read acknowledgements getting dropped on the gossip protocol.  If it was firewall related, the nodes wouldn't be able to talk to each other at all, so I think you're ok there.

There was a related issue ([CASSANDRA-16877](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16877)) of these types of messages appearing at startup, when the gossip state exceeded 128kb, but that was fixed in Cassandra 4.0.1.

On each of your nodes, have a look at the `system.peers` table.  In a K8s or containerized cluster you often see old nodes going down and being replaced with a new IP.  If there are old IPs hanging around in a stale gossip state somewhere, the cluster could be trying to communicate with those.

If there are old IPs there, go ahead and run a `nodetool assassinate <OLD_IP_ADDRESS>` to get rid of each.

Comment: In the log message I can see the IP and it is on each node the nodes own public IP. So it's like if the node could not talk with himself.

Comment: I did investigate further and checked the peers table on each cluster node. All entries are correct. I also tested shutting down the UFW firewall - then the messages did not appear any more (only uninvited guests try to connect to my public cluster). So it sees that the problem is caused by my firewall. But as the message only occurs every 10 minutes I think I can accept this warning in my log file.