# Why are connections to Cassandra nodes timing-out during low traffic periods?

Tags: cassandra

Why do Cassandra nodes report timeouts in the logs during low traffic periods?

The `system.log` on nodes report `ConnectTimeoutException` between nodes or "socket closed" errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

This article discusses an issue where a firewall configured with an idle connection timeout can close connections to local nodes and nodes in other data centres during low traffic periods.

### Cause

The TCP keepalive may not be appropriately configured for your environment. The default idle connection timeout is usually set to 2 hours (`7200` seconds) which means keepalive probes are not sent often enough for the firewall's idle connection timeout.

### Solution

To prevent connections between nodes from timing out, set the following network kernel settings:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w \
  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60 \
  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3 \
  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=10
```

These settings will keep the connection alive by sending 3 probes every 60 seconds with a 10-second gap between each probe. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I have a story about how these settings were a "silver bullet" for one cluster that I had worked on.  Absolutely need to do this in prod!